# Server communication between website and client application

Tags: php, vb.net, communication

How would I make a Visual Basic application talk to a web server? Someone will press something on the site and I want the application to display the information that the web site passes along to it.

Comment: There is a lot of ways to do this. What technologies can you use on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there are lots of ways to do this but simplest would be for the web application to write stuff into a database which the VB app displays. Unless I'm missing the obvious?

Comment: Yes but I need more specifics, how do I have the VB app detect the change?

Answer (score 0):

one way in SQL 2005/2008 would be to use [**xp_cmdshell**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx)

**Example:**

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir *.exe';
GO
```

This could be placed inside the stored procedure that does the insert/update etc.

This would run a custom executable, that in turn can 'communicate' with your VB application.